# useEffect doesn't wait Promise.all?

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I want to fetch data for every object in array passed as props (`rootComments`) and add the data to object properties:

```
useEffect(() => {
  rootComments.map(rootComment => {
    if (rootComment.kids) {
      rootComment.kidsText = []
      fetchKidsText(rootComment.kids)
    }
  })
  console.log(rootComments)
  rootComments.map(comment => console.log(Object.values(comment)))
}, [rootComments])

const fetchKidsText = async (ids) => {
  await Promise.all(
    ids.map(id => fetch(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json?print=pretty`).then(response => response.json()).then(result => {
      rootComments.map(comment => {
        if (comment.id === result.parent) {
          comment.kidsText = comment.kidsText.concat(result.text)
        }
      })
    }))
  );
}
```

It seems like it doesn't work, I can't render `rootComments.map(comment => comment.kidsText)` and I can't log it as `rootComments.map(comment => console.log(Object.values(comment)))` (acts like there's no new `kidsText` property) or as `rootComments.map(comment => console.log(comment.kidsText))` (returns empty array).
But. When I log `console.log(rootComments)` it returns array of objects with new `kidsText` property.

My first thought was that `useEffect()` doesn't wait for `rootComments` to fetch inside another component but it doesn't seem to be a problem so maybe it's something inside `fetchKidsText()` or with the way it interacts with `useEffect()`?

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with your code. I think the current answer by @kigiri sums up those issues pretty well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things are wrong with this code:

- You mutate your `rootComments` object without using `setState` (react can't update from it)
- You use `map` for iteration but discard the result
- Mix of `.then` in `async / await` function
- You don't return the value of `Promise.all` and instead `await` it

`.map` is not a for loop, either use `.forEach` or a `for..of` loop

As for your actual question, my first point is probably the main issue, show more code so we can confirm

> **edit** suggested alternative code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // get all the kids id, this create a single big array with every kids:
  const allKids = rootComments.flatMap(rootComment => rootComment.kids || [])

  // use a controller too cancel fetch request if component is unmounted
  // otherwhise, trying to setState if the component is unmounted will
  // mess react up:
  const controller = new AbortController()

  // we fetch all the kids at once instead of doing this in a map like before
  fetchKidsText(allKids, controller.signal)
    .then(setRootComment) // note that i'm using `.then` here,
    // because we can't await in hooks we must return a callback or undefined.
    .catch(err => {
      if (err.name === 'AbortError') return // we can safely ignore abort error
      // ? handle error here
    })
  return () => controller.abort()
}, [rootComments])

const fetchKidsText = async (ids, signal) => {
  // first we call the api and get everything a big result
  const results = await Promise.all(ids.map(async id => {
    const url = `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json?print=pretty`
    const res = await fetch(url, { signal })
    return res.json()
  }))

  // now what you were trying to do was merge every children text comment
  // since we got them all, just one filter should work:
  return rootComments.map(comment => {
    const children = results.filter(r => r.parent === comment.id)
    const kidsText = children.map(r => r.text)
    return { ...comments, kidsText }
  })
}
```

Don't use this code as is, I didn't test it's just to explain how I would have try to solve your problem with comments to explain my resoning.

Good luck !